# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error Failed to instantiate module printStation due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I am developing an application with anguarjs and taking an error following like this :

Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=u...)
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:38:98
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:37:180)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:37:349
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:37:180)
    at eb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:40:435)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:19:381

I read all suggestions about this error and applied but they are not usefull.
my layout page like this:

```
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/app/myApp.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/messages.js"></script>
</head>

        <body ng-app="myApp" class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">

   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

and my myApp.js page is like that:

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMessages', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

my controllers are in another folder and beginning like this:

```
myApp.controller('templateController', [ '$scope','$rootScope', 'SharedDataService', "templateFactory", "$log", "$uibModal", function ( $scope,$rootScope, SharedDataService,templateFactory, $log, $uibModal) {
.
.
.
```

Also I didnt create my own directive and I checked angular.js and angular-route.js are downloaded. Why am i taking this error ? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd comment this if I had the rep (as I'm not sure about it), but I don't think `ui.bootstrap` is being included anywhere on the page, which would cause the app to fail to instantiate.

EDIT: Could you provide the full lines of the debug output?